# How can I make apache read&write to a user's directory without setting a 777 permision

Tags: linux, apache

I setup a virtualhost for Apache server on Linux, set the document root to /home/someuser/www

Now the permission of /home/someuser/www is default, the problem is Apache can not write to /home/someuser/www

Is there a way to make sure Apache has ability to read&write to /home/someuser/www, I do not want to set www/ as 777.

At the moment, there is a folder named cache/ in www/, when apache generate cache files in cache/ folder, I want to use my user to make change to www/cache/*.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the `www-data` to your user group. As root, replace `<groupname>` by the user group name:

```
usermod -a -G <groupname> www-data
```

Allow the group to read/write in the folder and `setgid`:

```
chmod -R g+rws /home/someuser/www
```